Как в русифицированный пакетом babel документ LaTeX в некоторые места вставить китайские иероглифы?
Мне нужно в, условно, пяти местах в тексте документа, который русифицирован через пакет babel, вставить несколько иероглифов.
Например:
\documentclass[oneside, final, 14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\sloppy

\begin{document}

中~--- это иероглиф, означающий <<середина>>.

\end{document}

При трансляции pdflatex выдаёт:

! LaTeX Error: Unicode character 中 (U+4E2D)
not set up for use with LaTeX.

Как правильно вставить иероглиф в этом случае? Кодировка *.tex-файла UTF8, дистрибутив Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm) x86_64.

Через код символа вроде можно что угодно написать.

Основываясь на ответе с английской версии SO: можно использовать специальный пакет для таких случаев CJKutf8
\documentclass[oneside, final, 14pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\sloppy
\usepackage{CJKutf8}

\begin{document}
    \begin{CJK}{UTF8}{gbsn}
    中
    \end{CJK}~--- 
    это иероглиф, означающий <<середина>>.
\end{document}

Получилось примерно так:

PS: в выводе на pdf после компиляции тире присутствует, это его съели при пережатии в jpg и вставке в сообщение.
PPS: Проверял под MS Windows 10 в TexLive 2020, должно сработать и в Linux.
